# Image shows up in iPhone simulator but not ipad - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

When I go to select an image from my camera roll and display it in my view it doesn't appear on the Ipad simulator. It works great on the iphone. Here is my code

```
//--CONTROLS HOW TO PICK THE IMAGE WHEN THIS BUTTON IS CLICKED--\\
@IBAction func chooseImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//--AFTER THE IMAGED IS PICKED THIS BRINGS BACK THE VIEW--\\
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    println("Image Selected")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageToPost.image = image
    photoSelected = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `UIImageView` called `imageToPost` is not displayed correctly by the iPad simulator. Check your storyboard file and make sure the image view is correctly wired to the outlet.

Also, check any constraints that might push the image view off the screen.

Comment: I looked and it is linked up properly. I have an error specifically for when an image is not picked, the post with give an error and say please pick an image. This error does not occur on the iPhone but it does on the ipad. It is almost like it doesn't want to save the image after selecting it on the IPad

Comment: You should describe the error including any error messages in your original question.